# Aggregation with min and max of different fields, incl. output

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I hope you can help me with a problem, one of my first posts, so please bear with me, I do my best.

Given following data in db.offers

```
{ departement : 'C_TG', type : 'FLAT_1', offer: 500, req: 490 }
{ departement : 'C_TG', type : 'FLAT_1', offer: 600, req: 595 }
{ departement : 'F_TG', type : 'FLAT_1', offer: 600, req: 480 }
{ departement : 'C_TG', type : 'FLAT_7', offer: 900, req: 889 }
{ departement : 'C_TG', type : 'FLAT_1', offer: 460, req: 454 }
{ departement : 'F_TG', type : 'FLAT_4', offer: 600, req: 590 }
{ departement : 'C_TG', type : 'FLAT_4', offer: 601, req: 599 }
{ departement : 'D_TG', type : 'FLAT_1', offer: 422, req: 420 }
{ departement : 'D_TG', type : 'FLAT_7', offer: 600, req: 500 }
```

I would like to aggregate the data to get the lowest offer and highest request (req) for a specific type, **including the departement (!!)** which is responsible. 
Example result:

```
{ type: 'FLAT_1' offer: 422, offer_departement: 'D_TG', req: 595, req_departement: 'F_TG' }
{ type: 'FLAT_4' offer: 600, offer_departement: 'F_TG', req: 599, req_departement: 'C_TG' }
{ type: 'FLAT_7' offer: 600, offer_departement: 'D_TG', req: 889, req_departement: 'C_TG' }
```

Up to now my best result was something like

```
[ { _id: { type: "FLAT_1", offer_departement: "D_TG" }, req: 595 } ]
```

But here all info regarding the "request info" was missing, so it doesnt really make sense ..
I already grouped and sorted, also did multiple group stages and so on, but either I get a whole list of items not taking the "$min" in account, or I am unable to get the departement into offer_departement...

My most current approach before I decided to ask for help is

```
db.prices.aggregate ([
        {
            $match : {
                offer : {
                    $ne : "0",
                },
                request : {
                    $ne : "0",
                },
            }
        },
        {
            $group : {
                _id : {
                    type : '$type',
                    dep : '$departement',
                },
                offer : {
                    $min : '$offer',
                },
                request : {
                    $max : '$req',
                }
            }
        },
    ]);
```

But of course the results are far from what I am aiming for, I tried dozens of answers from, also from SO, but I don't get it.

I really would appreciate some help !

best regards, Simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of [`$min`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/) and [`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) what you need to do here instead is [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) the input first and then use the [`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) and [`$last`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/) accumulators for the grouping boundaries:

```
db.prices.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "offer": { "$gt": 0 } , "req": { "$gt": 0 } } },
  { "$sort": { "type": 1, "offer": 1, "req": 1 } },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$type",
    "offer_departement": { "$first": "$departement" },
    "offer": { "$first": "$offer" },
    "req_departement": { "$last": "$departement" },
    "req": { "$last": "$req" }
  }},
  { "$sort": { "req": 1 } }
])
```

Returns:

```
{
        "_id" : "FLAT_1",
        "offer_departement" : "D_TG",
        "offer" : 422,
        "req_departement" : "C_TG",
        "req" : 595
}
{
        "_id" : "FLAT_4",
        "offer_departement" : "F_TG",
        "offer" : 600,
        "req_departement" : "C_TG",
        "req" : 599
}
{
        "_id" : "FLAT_7",
        "offer_departement" : "D_TG",
        "offer" : 600,
        "req_departement" : "C_TG",
        "req" : 889
}
```

Also a bit better "index usage wise" is to use [`$gt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/gt/) rather than [`$ne`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/) since an "inequality" cannot efficiently use an index where a "range" ( even as open ) can. So as long as those are never negative amounts then this would be a better approach.

Note also that [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) has no defined order of output, so if you expect a specific order then apply a [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) after the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) as well.